# C program that finds out 2 most common letters in a string, and reverses them in the same string

Tags: c

This is what I have at the moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ENG_LETTERS 26
#define STR_LEN 100

int main()
{
    int countArray[ENG_LETTERS] = {0};
    char str[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    char engChar = 'a' - 1;
    int length = 0;
    int i , j = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    printf("Please enter a string:\n");
    fgets(str , STR_LEN , stdin);
    length = strlen(str);
    for(i = 0 ; i <= length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '\n')
        {
            str[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < ENG_LETTERS;i++)
    {
        engChar++;
        for(j = 0;j <= length - 1;j++)
        {
            if(str[j] == engChar)
            {
                countArray[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    engChar = 'a'- 1;
    for(i = 0; i <= ENG_LETTERS - 1;i++)
    {
        engChar++;
        printf("There are %d %c letters\n", countArray[i],engChar);

    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This basically lets me check how many letters are in the whole. I tried searching the whole internet to check how can I find the 2 most frequent, and reverse them in the string*. Am I doing something wrong? How can I improve?

(When I say reverse them in a string, I mean that instead of " i love this game i do i do " there will be " o live thos game o di o di" since "i" is the most frequent and "o" is the second most.)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Does it work? Maybe you want a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) then?

Comment: Read the title....That's the question. I need someone to help me with the program, and how I can improve with it to achieve the desired program.

Comment: The title does not contain a question - it contains a requirement

Comment: Exactly. That is what I require, and I ask how can I achieve the requirement. Now , if you can help me it would be great. I am tired of searching for nothing.

Comment: So, just to clarify... you've already written 28 loops, and you're wondering how to loop through your data to find the two highest values, and then how to loop through the string to swap those values?  Do you understand what your current code does?  Because all the tools you need are already in your own code.

Comment: You need to show the community better efforts, it is not clear what your doubts are. Where is the point that seems a dead end for you? Don't ask people just to do your entire homework for you.

Comment: Scott, yes,  I do not know how to do so. Usually when I go here, people posts codes showing their way to solve the problem.
And yes, I know I am new to this community, and don't always follow the basic rules, but all I see was people complaining that I don't have a question in my titles and probably didn't read the whole post. I don't see how it  is useful.

Comment: How convenient!

Comment: @WebertS.Lima My dead end is where I stopped writing. I can not figure out how Do I find  the 2 most big chars in the string, print them , and then reverse them in the string itself.

Comment: I'll say this, as politely as possible, and then bow out.  You won't get far in programming by simply copying code you find on the internet, and not understanding it.  You advance by experimenting, and playing with what a language can do, and learning how to manipulate that.  All you need in your solution is a few more loops, if statements, counters, and setting variables.  You got such a negative response because you can get yourself past the dead end you mentioned.  And if you can't, you can at least show us what you tried, and we can help from there.

Answer (score 0):

here is sample, how you can count 2 most frequent symbols:

```
int freq[ENG_LETTERS] = { 0 };
char str[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
char *pStr = str;
int i, max, max2; // max - most frequent one, max2 - second most frequent

printf("Please enter a string:\n");
fgets(str, STR_LEN, stdin);

while (*pStr) {
    if ((*pStr >= 'a') && (*pStr <= 'z'))
        ++freq[(*pStr) - 'a']; // convert from symbol to index
    ++pStr;
}

max = max2 = 0; // lets assume that first letter (a) is most frequent one
for (i = 1; i < ENG_LETTERS; ++i) {
    if (freq[i] > freq[max]) {
        max2 = max; max = i; // save old max and update new max
    } else if (freq[i] > freq[max2])
        max2 = i;
}
max += 'a'; // convert indexes back to symbols
max2 += 'a';
printf("%c %c\n", max, max2);

pStr = str; // swap max symbols
while (*pStr) {
    if (*pStr == max) *pStr = max2;
    else if (*pStr == max2) *pStr = max;
    ++pStr;
}
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

One proposal, the idea is to:

1. compute frequencies
2. sort the results with qsort and a comparator function
3. swap the 2 characters in the string

   ```
   static int frequencyComparator (void const *a, void const *b)
   {
       const Histo* ha=a;
       const Histo* hb=b;
       return hb->freq-ha->freq;
   }

   struct Histo
   {
       char c;
       int freq;
   };

   Histo histo[ENG_LETTERS]={0};
   char str[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
   char *pStr = str;
   printf("Please enter a string:\n");
   fgets(str, STR_LEN, stdin);

   int index=0;
   while(*pStr!=0)
   {
       index=(*pStr)-'a';
       if(index>=0 && index<26)
       {
           histo[index].c=(*pStr);
           histo[index].freq++; 
       }
       pStr++;
   }

   qsort (histo, ENG_LETTERS, sizeof(Histo), frequencyComparator);

   if(histo[0].freq>0 && histo[1].freq>0)
   {
       printf("%c %c\n", histo[0].c, histo[1].c);
       pStr = str;
       while(*pStr!=0)
       {
           if(*pStr==histo[0].c) *pStr=histo[1].c
           else if(*pStr==histo[1].c) *pStr=histo[0].c
           pStr++;
       }
   }

   printf("%s\n", str);
   ```